# Example where character table and Frobenius-Schur index doesn't determine the group.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

It is well known that the complex character table does not determine the group. The classical example always given is of a pair of groups of order $8$,  [the dihedral group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) $D_8$ and the [Quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group)  $Q_8$.

However these have different real representation theory - $\mathbb{R}[Q_8] = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{R}[D_8] = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

This can be deduced from the complex character table as the Frobenius-Schur index of the 2 dimensional representation is 1 for $D_8$ and -1 for $Q_8$.

This then gives that the groups are non isomorphic.

I was wondering what the smallest (or just any) example of two non isomorphic groups with identical character tables and Frobenius Schur indicators was.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @peterag no problem, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two nonisomorphic nonabelian groups of order $p^3$ for odd primes $p$ have the same character tables and the same Frobenius-Schur indicators - these are $0$ for all except the trivial character. I would guess that the nonabelian groups of order $27$ are the smallest such examples, but I haven't checked.